# Strange output in a script converted from Python to Ruby, why?

Tags: python, ruby

have tried to convert this [gist](https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/5526230) in ruby, this is my code:

```
$char_map = ('!.' + '0123456789' + 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').scan(/./)
$int_map  = Hash.new
$char_map.each_with_index {|v,k| $int_map[v] = k }
$cutoff = ($char_map.count) - 11

# Converts an integer to its text-encoded form.
def to_chars(value)

  if value < $cutoff
    return $char_map[value]
  end
  value -= $cutoff
  out = []
  while value != 0
    value, rem = value.divmod($char_map.count)
    out.push($char_map[rem])
  end
  # handle when value == cutoff
  if !out
    out.push($char_map[value])
  end
  out.push($char_map[$cutoff + out.count - 1])
  out.reverse!
  return out.join('')

end


# Converts characters from the provided string back into their integer
# representation, and returns both the desired integer as well as the number
# of bytes consumed from the character string (this function can accept a
# string that is the result of a concatenation of results from to_chars() ).
def to_val(chars)

  chars = chars.scan(/./)
  first = $int_map[chars[0]]
  if first < $cutoff
    return first, 1
  end
  first -= $cutoff - 1
  dec = []
  for ch in chars[1..1+first] do
    dec.push($int_map[ch])
  end
  value = dec.pop() + $cutoff
  m = $char_map.count

  while dec != []
    value += m * dec.pop()
    m *= $char_map.count
  end
  return value, first + 1

end

# Converts a sequence of integers into a string that represents those
# integers.
def from_sequence(lst)
  lst.map! {|int| to_chars(int)}
  return lst.join('')
end
# Converts a string that rappresents a sequence of integers back into a 
# a list of integers
def from_string(str)
  out = []
  i = 0
  while i < str.length
      this, used = to_val(str[i, str.length - i])
    out.push(this)
    i += used
  end
  return out
end

p to_chars(123456789)
p to_val(to_chars(123456789))
p from_string(from_sequence([123456789,4688]))
```

(Sorry for global vars ect... is only for testing, when works fit all in own class)

The error is in last line, instead of print back the `[123456789, 4688]` array print `[7901231212, 4688]`

Why? where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stored the encoded text length in the last character (when reversed, it became the first),  so in your `to_var` method, `first` stored the encoded text length after `first -= $cutoff - 1`. However, by iterating `chars[1..1+first]`, you actually visited `first + 1` characters. You should use exclusive range here: `chars[1...1+first]`, or `chars[1..first]`.

Besides, ruby regards empty array as `true` value, only `false` and `nil` are considered as `false`. So in your `to_chars` method, the condition `if !out` will never meet since you have assigned an array to `out`. You should use `if out.empty?` here.

Not sure if there are other mistakes.